# Can not find cl::Error class in OpenCL library

Tags: c++, error-handling, opencl

I saw in some code that in OpenCL library, there is a class named `cl::Error` by which the error and type of error in `OpenCL` code can be catched. But when I added in my code, like this

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

int main()
{
  std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
  cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

  assert(platforms.size() > 0);

  auto myPlatform = platforms.front();
  std::cout << "Using platform: " << myPlatform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << std::endl;

  std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
  myPlatform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

  auto myDevice = devices.front();
  std::cout<< "Using device: "<< myDevice.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

  std::ifstream helloworldfile("helloWorldKernel.cl");
  std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(helloworldfile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  cl::Program::Sources source(1,std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length() + 1));

  cl::Context context(myDevice);
  cl::Program program(context,source);

  cl::CommandQueue queue(context,myDevice);

  try
  {
    program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");
  } catch(cl::Error& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::cout;
  }

  int err;
  int szChar = 16;
  char  buf[szChar];

  cl::Buffer memBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(char) * szChar);

  cl::Kernel kernel(program, "helloWorld", &err);

  if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    std::cout<<" Error in creating kernel, error: "<< err << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  } 


  kernel.setArg(0,memBuf);

  queue.enqueueTask(kernel);

  err =  queue.enqueueReadBuffer(memBuf,CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf);

  if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    std::cout<<" Error in reading from device, error: "<< err << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  std::cout << buf;
  std::cin.get();

  return 0;

}
```

I got the error that the

```
helloWorld.cc:46:12: error: expected type-specifier
   } catch (cl::Error& e)
            ^
helloWorld.cc:46:21: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
   } catch (cl::Error& e)
                     ^
helloWorld.cc:46:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
helloWorld.cc:46:21: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘&’ token
helloWorld.cc:46:23: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
   } catch (cl::Error& e)
                       ^
helloWorld.cc:46:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
   } catch (cl::Error& e)
```

I was wondering if the class exist or at least exist in specific version of library OpenCL, if so, how should be invoke it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to define `__CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` or if you're using the more up to date `#include <CL/cl2.hpp>` you need `CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS`.

The define needs to be before you include the opencl header.

Comment: By `#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` in `<CL/cl.hpp>`, I again got the same error. nothing changed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you tried

Comment: I made the question simple, but now I uploaded the complete sample code in which the error I mentioned I got.

Comment: you need to put the define before you include opencl, ideally put in in the compiler settings

Comment: Thanks for the point. It works, but could you please tell me why I should define it before includes.

Comment: because otherwise it doesn't work! thats how `#define works`, it only affects code after it, if it isn't defined before the header then the code inside the `#ifdef` simply doesn't exist

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: ITs actually `CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` for open cl2.